# disable rsh login on sshd server

Tags: ssh, rsh

I have a machine 192.168.110.170, and I can login with rsh usrname@192.168.110.170 at another machine 192.168.110.169. When login, command `netstat | grep 169` gives

> tcp 0 0 hostname:ssh 192.168.110.169:33551 ESTABLISHED

the hostname above is the hostname of 192.168.110.170

It seems rsh connected to ssh server,my question is how to disable this? I did't find any configuration in the sshd_config file, sshd_config is as follows

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
#PasswordAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
```

when I stop ssh on 192.168.10.170 with `service ssh stop`,rsh gives an error

> ssh:connct to host 192.168.110.170 port 22:Connection refused

how can I disable rsh connect to ssh without stop ssh on server?

Comment: rsh run on port 513/514

Comment: yes, but it connect to ssh server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't find anything in the sshd configuration because OpenSSHd does not do rsh.

Most probably on your client `rsh` is a symlink to the `ssh` binary.

```
pi@esszimmer:~ $ ls -l `which rsh`
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 May 27  2016 /usr/bin/rsh -> /etc/alternatives/rsh
pi@esszimmer:~ $ ls -l /etc/alternatives/rsh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 May 27  2016 /etc/alternatives/rsh -> /usr/bin/ssh
```

When running `rsh` you are actually doing an SSH connection.

Another indication is the output of your `netcat` command, which shows that you are connected to the SSH port. If you were connecting via rsh it would show there as `rsh` instead of `ssh`.

You don't have anything to worry about.